# Django migration failed

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, backend

```
$ python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb [DEBUG] (MainThread) Using proactor: IocpProactor Operations to perform:   Synchronize unmigrated apps: humanize, messages, registration, staticfiles   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, groups, home, institutes, questions, sessions, student, users Synchronizing apps without migrations:   Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL... Running migrations:   Applying institutes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Freelance\gear\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: ERREUR:  la relation « coordinator » n'existe pas
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: use code formatting and explain your problem

Comment: And please show `institutes.0001_initial`.

Comment: Why are you using the [`--run-syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-run-syncdb) argument? It isn't recommended unless you have a specific reason.